# WCF RESTful: Adding a service reference in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, visual-studio-2010, rest, .net-4.0

I'm trying to add a *service reference* to a RESTful WCF service in Visual Studio 2010.

Actually, Visual Studio 2010 doesn't discover any service in my solution.

My question is: is this possible using RESTful WCF services?

Comment: If this isn't possible, I understand creating a RESTful WCF service client is as easy as executing an HTTP request with the appropiate verb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the online WCF RESTful Service template to create your RESTful WCF service? This template uses a .cs file instead of a .svc + .svc.cs file. Which seems to make the "Discover Services In Solution" break (Does work against .svc + .asmx services however). A possible work around would be to implement it in the form of .svc + .svc.cs.

I've just tested this locally by creating a service using the RESTful template, adding a "WCF Service" using the add new file menu and moving the code from "Service1.cs" in there, and modifying the route table in Global.asax.cs to

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("TestService", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(TestService)));
```

Comment: I see. Right, I'm using this online template for WCF RESTful services. It seems I'm going go create my own service client instead of regular one, because my scenario has low complexity: doing an HTTP request using a web request or something like that should be fine. Thank you for your answer.